# Spacing around a custom operator with stacked elements using centernot

Tags: spacing, math-operators

I am using an operator with the definition

`\newcommand{\tom}[2]{{\displaystyle\mathrel{\mathop{\to}^{#1}_{#2}}}}`

with negation

`\newcommand{\ntom}[2]{\centernot{\displaystyle\mathrel{\mathop{\to}^{#1}_{#2}}}}`

The operator looks like this, with markup `u\tom km w`:

[image]

and the negation looks like this, `u\ntom km w`:

[image]

Notice in `\tom` the u and w are smashed up against the arrow, whereas in the negation there is spacing around it. I'm not sure which one looks better, but is there a way to keep it consistent?

I'm also not too comfortable with using `\displaystyle`, but it was the only way I could see to ensure the k and m stay above and below the arrow in `\mathrel`/`\mathop`.

Comment: the `\mathrel` is being negated by the outer `{}` which makes a mathord. You can use `\limits` rather than displaystyle to force the over position

Comment: Note you might replace `\tom`  with a simple `\xrightarrow[m]{k}`.

Comment: @Bernard I didn't know about that, thanks. I just tried it though and when I do k-1 instead of k it lengthens the arrow, and I'm not sure how I feel about that.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle What's the syntax for `\limits`? I'm trying various things and I get massive numbers of errors.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Nevermind, I got it, thanks. Spacing problem remains though.

Comment: @MathSamuel: Yes, it's designed to adapt to the text above and below. However, if you don't want this feature, you may use `\mathclap{k-1}`, in your example (load `mathtools`, which defines this command, in the place of `amsmath`).

Comment: @Bernard `\xrightarrow[\mathclap{#2}]{\mathclap{#1}}` seems to fix both problems. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can keep it consistent:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,centernot}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\tom}{\n@tom{\n@tom@to}}
\newcommand{\ntom}{\n@tom{\n@tom@nto}}

\newcommand{\n@tom}[3]{\overunderset{#2}{#3}{#1}}

\newcommand{\n@tom@to}{\rightarrow\mathrel{\vphantom{\not}}}
\newcommand{\n@tom@nto}{\centernot\rightarrow}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$u\tom{k}{m}w$ $u\ntom{k}{m}w$

\end{document}
```

[image]

The seemingly mysterious programming style is aimed of splitting the job in layers. One main macro `\n@tom` takes as first argument the type of arrow and then the top and bottom limits. The two types of arrow are defined separately, so as to make it easier to modify just them.

For instance, if we load `amssymb` instead of `centernot` and change the two final definitions into

```
\newcommand{\n@tom@to}{\rightarrow}
\newcommand{\n@tom@nto}{\nrightarrow}
```

we'd get

[image]

which I think is better.

Comment: I found an alternative solution that looks the same, using Bernard's suggestion: `\xrightarrow[\mathclap{#2}]{\mathclap{#1}}` and `\centernot` on that. I have to think about the `\nrightarrow`. Thanks for your answer.